# Save and Cancel Button not working

Tags: button, case-object

Can any one help me out ?

As per the requirement , i have created a  vf page ,i have been using the standard button functionality SAVE and CANCEL .But the problem is the Save and Cancel button does not work.when i give the data click on save it should save the data and when we click on the cancel button it should go back to the previous page where the user was.The button does not work .Any help very much appreciated.

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  extensions="MassCloseCasesController" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:SectionHeader title="Close Cases"/>
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Both">
          <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
           <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Case Information" >
             <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Status}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Reason_For_Resolution__c}" label="Reason For Resolution"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Comment__c}" label="Internal Comments"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c}" label="Do Not Send Email Case Closure"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Code :

```
public with sharing class MassCloseCasesController {

    public MassCloseCasesController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    List<Case> cases = [Select ID,CaseNumber From Case where id = :ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id')];

        System.debug('size = '+ cases.size());
    }

        public PageReference save()

    {  


         return null;   


    }
 public PageReference cancel()
    {       

       return null;
}


}
```

Comment: don't use  extensions="MassCloseCasesController" just remove it and then try once

Comment: @RatanPaul:when i remove the extensions ,click on save button ,it creates another record.

Comment: then change your save and cancel method name

Comment: @RatanPaul:When i removed the ext ,the class created and method got deleted.Their is no class and no method.

Comment: Yaah add the ext and then change your save and cancel method name. and call the newly save method from Save button and perform update dml on Case. and for cancel button you may want redirect to case detail page then pagereference

Comment: @RatanPaul:CAN U HELP ME OUT WITH AN Example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31642/discussion-between-ratan-paul-and-nikkey).

Answer (score 2):

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  extensions="MassCloseCasesController" sidebar="false">
      <apex:form >
        <apex:SectionHeader title="Close Cases"/>
          <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Both">
              <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
               <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Case Information" >
                 <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Status}"/>
                 <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Reason_For_Resolution__c}" label="Reason For Resolution"/>
                 <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Comment__c}" label="Internal Comments"/>
                 <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c}" label="Do Not Send Email Case Closure"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MassCloseCasesController {

    public Case objCase {get;set;}
    public MassCloseCasesController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        objCase = new Case();
        Id idCase = controller.getId();
        objCase = [SELECT Id, Status, Reason_For_Resolution__c, Comment__c, Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c FROM Case WHERE Id : idCase];
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {  
        update objCase;

         return new pagereference('/'+objCase.Id);   


    }
    public PageReference cancel()
    {       
      return new pagereference('/'+objCase.Id);   
    }
}
```

try with this